# Chemicals additive resistant to acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am an ink developer. I'm am working on an ink to withstand chemical alteration after curing. I am having trouble defeating the acetone portion of my testing. Does anyone know of an additive that would help my alcohol based ink resistant to acetone ( and other) chemicals?

Comment: Just an idea. Have you tried using simple water ?

Comment: Actually, I have not

Comment: Making an ink resistant to wide spectrum of solvents isn't trivial. The only approach I can come with is to use something that reacts with air on drying or is otherwise altered after it is applied. The exact details depend on your use case, so if you can share ? Is it an ink for a printer, artistic purposes, permanent marker or something else?

Comment: In short form, permanent marking, indoors and out. A company I found sells a chemical resistant ink but it's $440 per gallon and I just can't justify that.  I was hoping to modify an existing ink to have these properties and so far I have made it resist isopropyl and denatured alcohol with pine rosin !

Comment: What is the ink applied to, and how it is cured? There are several (mostly pigment-based) inks used in pens like Uni-Ball Signo 207, Sakura Pigma Micron or Pentel EnerGel Permanent, which you might want to look into in case you are dealing with paper or similar material. The ink used in these pens can withstand acetone and the majority of other organic solvents.

Comment: Air cured, applied to painted drums, pallets, lumber,steel beams.

Comment: @DevCrew I see, you might want to [edit] this info into the question. In that case, laser engraving, chemical etching or laminated labels would be better than ink labeling, I would think.

Comment: This is most likely accurate but I'm so invested at this point, plus now I'm fixated on figuring it out. I was proud of the pine resin method

Answer (score 2):

Look into [reactive inks and dyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_dye). Though some require fixation, e.g., an alkali, there are also [single-bath reactive inks and dyes](https://textilelearner.net/reactive-dyes-classification-dyeing-mechanism/).

Since these inks directly change the chemical nature of cellulose, they cannot be removed without removing a layer of the substrate. This is analogous to [skin stains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_acid) careless chemists get when working with nitric acid, which, "stains human skin yellow due to its reaction with the keratin." The stain stays until the skin wears off.  <sub>[What, me?? Oh, hardly ever! That would be a blot on my escutcheon.]</sub>

That said, some might not resist attack from bleaches, leaving a clear ("leuco") dye. However, the mark might still be revealed by IR or UV photography, or by chemical reduction.

Comment: Good reads ! Thank you so much. I've been thinking of potassium permanganate as a stain but that stuff scares me with the alcohol base.

Comment: Permanganates *might* leave a permanent stain... however, the black MnO2 can be removed with bisulfites, possibly removing the coloring -- or not.

Comment: If at all, what could be something I could add, similar to Permanganate ( stain wise ) but without the harsh opposition to an alcohol base ?

Comment: nanocrystalline graphite, possibly a mix of aluminum lake dyes

Comment: We had a stain removal center in our lab Last resort was permanganate followed by bisulfite and detergent to remove the MnO2.  Our motto "If we could not remove the stain we fixed the hole"

Comment: That is awesome hahaha I love it. Thank you !